# Python - Replace Value in Text at Random

Tags: python, search, random, replace

I have two open source files I've been messing around with, one file is a small macro script I'm working with, second is a txt file filled with commands I'd like to insert in to the first script in a random order within their respective lines. I've managed to come up with this script for searching and replacing the values, but not to insert them in a random order from the second txt file.

```
def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExp):
    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
        if searchExp in line:
            line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
        sys.stdout.write(line)

replaceAll('C:/Users/USERACCOUNT/test/test.js','InterSearchHere', RandomValueFrom2ndTXT)
```

Any help if greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
import itertools as it

def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExps):
    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
        if searchExp in line:
            line = line.replace(searchExp,next(replaceExps))
        sys.stdout.write(line)

with open('SecondFile','r') as f:
    replaceExp=f.read().splitlines()
random.shuffle(replaceExps)         # randomize the order of the commands
replaceExps=it.cycle(replaceExps)   # so you can call `next(replaceExps)`

replaceAll('C:/Users/USERACCOUNT/test/test.js','InterSearchHere', replaceExps)
```

Each time you call `next(replaceExps)` you get a different line from the second file.

When a finite iterator is exhausted, `next(replaceExps)` will raise a `StopIteration` exception. To prevent that from ever happening, I used `itertools.cycle` to make the shuffled command list repeat ad infinitum.